# Yahoo stock ticker is not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am working on stock ticker and search number of site for stock ticker. I found a ticker in [this site](http://techblog.shanock.com/articles/9/simple-php-stock-ticker-and-javascript-marquee-for-valid-xhtml).

But I am getting error while displaying the screen - where it is going wrong?

[image]

I feel error in below code, but I am not figuring it how to fix it.

```
        // ...format, and output them. I made the symbols into links to Yahoo's stock pages.
        echo "<span class=\"stockbox\"><a href=\"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=".$stock_info[0]."\">".$stock_info[0]."</a> ".sprintf("%.2f",$stock_info[1])." <span style=\"";
        // Green prices for up, red for down
        if ($stock_info[2]>=0) { echo "color: #009900;\">&uarr;";   }
        elseif ($stock_info[2]<0) { echo "color: #ff0000;\"> }
        echo sprintf("%.2f",abs($stock_info[2]))."</span></span>\n";
        // Done!
        fclose($local_file); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Ben are you able to see the screenshot? iam unable to figureout the error, so that only iam asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error exists on line 5:

```
elseif ($stock_info[2]<0) { echo "color: #ff0000;\"> }
```

Should be

```
elseif ($stock_info[2]<0) { echo "color: #ff0000;\">"; }
```

Or

```
elseif ($stock_info[2]<0) { echo 'color: #ff0000;">'; }
```

As a rule, I always do what I can to avoid escaping `quotes`, this forces me to know when a quote is closed or open. For example, I would rather do

```
echo "My name is '$bernard'";   
//and if the " quotes are compulsory
echo 'My name is "'.$bernard.'"';
```

Than

```
echo "My name is \"bernard\"";
```

It's cleaner, and easier to read.

### Update

I didn't notice the URL, it's a *.htm file. For the code to even run, you need to run it through a server that can process PHP code :)

Answer (score 2):

You must run it through a web server with PHP support.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the quotes on this line:

```
elseif ($stock_info[2]<0) { echo "color: #ff0000;\"> }
```

Comment: developer, nobody will do your coding for you. Go through a tutorial, a book or a course about the language and you should be able to do correct syntax yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem
looked in the original site it said

> "If it was a problem with the stockcache directory, the script would
>   likely print “0.00 ↑0.00” for every stock entry. Rather, it looks as
>   if your HTTP server is spitting out the PHP code instead of parsing it
>   properly. This could be related to a server misconfiguration or
>   conflicting code elsewhere on the page. Unfortunately, I can’t be more
>   specific without knowing much more of the context, such as the the
>   source code of the webpage in question, server OS, HTTPD and PHP
>   version, and their configurations."

looked up in the hosting help in found that it had to have php allowed (if it was within the html), had to create an .htaccess file an add the line the hosting company gave me, after a short chat with their support the issue was solved